# How to access this in javascript modular pattern in private methods?

Tags: javascript

How can I access this (the object this) while using a private method using the javascript module pattern?

I do not understand how this works, I am still trying to learn it.

```
var o = o || {};
o.Assets = (function() {
    "use strict";

    function privateFunc() {
        // how do I get this.assetQ?
    }

    function Assets(assetQ) {
        this.init(assetQ);
    };
    Assets.prototype.assetQ = [];
    Assets.prototype.cache = [];
    Assets.prototype.callback = false;
    /*
Initialize the assets
*/
    Assets.prototype.init = function(assetQ) {
        if (assetQ) {
            this.assetQ = assetQ;
        }
    };
    return Assets;
})();
```

Comment: *How can I access this?* What is "this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `privateFunc` from a method of `Assets`, use `privateFunc.call( this )` then use `this.assetQ` inside `privateFunc`.

```
function privateFunc() {
    console.log(this.assetQ);
}
```

...

```
Assets.prototype.init = function(assetQ) {
    if (assetQ) {
        this.assetQ = assetQ;
    }
    privateFunc.call( this );
};
```

If your private functions take arguments, you can pass them in `.call` normally after the context argument:

```
privateFunc.call( this, 1, 2, 3 );

function privateFunc( a, b, c ) {
  //a is 1, b is 2 etc..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am still learning so this has helped alot :) Is this generally the way it is done when using a modular pattern?

Comment: @user2251919 well there are other alternatives of course and they work just as well. Just be consistent with one way is the most important thing.